# Remove Line Break or Carriage Return

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have in my database values like:

```
HD1_DES    |HD1_HAS    |HD
-----------|-----------|----------
25023132-1 |24974875-3 |25045370-0
24826798-6 |24829389-12|25045328-0
```

But when I retrieve them with my dataGridView, I have this:

```
HD1_DES    |HD1_HAS    |HD
-----------|-----------|----------
25023132-  |24974875-  |25045370- 
1          |3          |0
24826798-  |24829389-  |25045328-
6          |12         |0
```

For retrieve I use TemplateFields in my gridview.

in my label control, I've tried fix this using:

```
HtmlEncode="false"
```

I tried to replace using: Text='<%# ((string)Eval("id1Des")).Replace("\n", "") %>

in the SP in SQL I tried:

```
Select REPLACE(REPLACE([ID1_DESDE], CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') AS 'ID1D'.
```

And in the code using a DataReader I tried:

```
sacLote.Id1Desde = dr["ID1D"].ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

But I still do not get results.

Comment: Are you sure that the line-breaks are not because of a small column size?

Comment: are you asking about `dataGridView` or `gridview`, exactly? you mention both and they are different things. please, clarify your question

Comment: Is a gridview control, 
I tried modifing header size, for example ______HD1_HAS______
the problem seems solved, but... I have to retrieve 25 columns and for user's convenience most of them must be on screen without moving with scroll bar.

I addition some values are for example 12345123-0, others 1234-2, and others JHUWE93849212342-23. The headers are not the same length.

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely caused by a too narrow column. Make it wider, so it can accommodate the values as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right, If I modify the column size with more characters on the header. This works for presentation.

But, when I run debug mode I have values like:
25045370-0\r\n.